# Logstash JSON Parsing from RabbitMQ

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch, logstash

I am getting the following Message from RabbitMQ, I think JSON received from RabbitMQ has BOM

```
{"ID":"811b7858-a926-479f-939a-2b0ab17de855","Name":"Johnson","Age": "30", "Work":"Engineer","Timestamp":"4/13/2015 10:53:29 AM"}
```

When i am saving that into Elastic search am getting it as below:

```
{
"_index": "logstash-2015.04.13",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "AUyxO4R8g98unoWRM4eU",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "message": "{"ID":"811b7858-a926-479f-939a-2b0ab17de855",","Name":"Johnson","Age": "30", "Work":"Engineer","Timestamp":"4/13/2015 10:53:29 AM"}",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-04-13T05:23:29.935Z",
    "type": "Employees"
    }
}
```

But i would like them to be stored as

```
{
"_index": "logstash-2015.04.13",
"_type": "logs",
"_id": "AUyxO4R8g98unoWRM4eU",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
    "ID":"811b7858-a926-479f-939a-2b0ab17de855",
    "Name":"Johnson",
    "Age": "30",
    "Work":"Engineer",
    "Timestamp":"4/13/2015 10:53:29 AM"
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2015-04-13T05:23:29.935Z",
    "type": "Employees" 
    }
}
```

I tried json filter. but it is not working.

Comment: Is there really a question mark at the beginning of the message field?

Comment: No i think it was added when i was copy pasting it here. Updated the post

Comment: The json filter should work just fine then. What does your filter look like? What happens? Anything interesting in the logs (you may have to turn up the loglevel with `--verbose` or `--debug`)? The json _codec_ should also work just fine.

Comment: I think the JSON has BOM it is showing question markwhen i copy paste it in notepad++, is there a way to remove BOM in logstash?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate). So what the question again? Is the BOM actually part of the message you get from RabbitMQ? Please adjust the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try json filter for logstash which will convert message string to json format

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    remove_field => ["message"]
  }
}
```